# is there a way to give format to a textview on a xib file on iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uitextview, textview

I am stuck trying to formatting a textview, because I want to make a nice but simple looking textview but I cant manage to do it. been looking all around but havent been able to do so. So now I plead to your expertise and ask for help in the matter.
All I want to do is format the text in a way that people be able to read it properly, example:

## Recipie

**Ingredients**:
1 Cup of rise
1 1/2 tea spuns of cinnamon
1 table spun of karo.

**Procedure**:
start by adding the ....

end placing every thing in a big bowl and enjoy.

as simple as that but it wont let me do it. so please if there is any genius looking to help
I will appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Hi, is that data can be editable or just want to display?

Comment: Just to display. and I have never ever used web view, because I have heard it does cause trouble when user taps, and at risk of sounding kind of a noob, I have non experience with it. so if you insist on web-view any example will be awesome. Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THANKS TO EVERY ONE, BUT I WAS TRYING TO AVOID THE UIWEBVIEW BECAUSE OF THE CRASHES PROBLEMS I HEARD, AND I FOUND AN EASIEST WAY TO MAKE IT TO WORK THE WAY THAT I NEEDED, I DECIDE TO USE LABELS (AS THE BOLD TEXT) AND TEXTVIEWS TO DISPLAY THE NORMAL TEXT; GIVING THEM THE FONT AND SIZE YOU WANT, AND ITS WORKING FINE. YOU CAN EVEN USE THEM IN A SCROLLVIEW IF NEEDED. LOL.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a `UIWebView` with an HTML document. That will give you the ultimate format capabilities.

Comment: Would the down-voter care to explain the reason for the down-vote? Or are we just sniping reputation here?

Comment: While I wouldn't agree with the downvote, a caveat about using them in certain cases might be in order. I.e., webview's eat all touches, so it makes them impractical to use in certain cases (i.e., table/grid cells, scrollviews) unless the webview's frame is set to the size of the document, then it'd work for scrolling — It'll still eat taps though.

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly put this into a UIWebView, that way you can use html and css formatting the way you want. You would have to do too many workarounds to to change the text sizes of the different parts of it and have to subclass and other nonsense.

Is there any reason that you need to use a textview?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that for anything involving multiple fonts or custom alignments, the best thing is to write it in HTML and use a UIWebView.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use JTextView code. It's not complete (editing support is what's not ready for prime time), but usable for text display (read: non-editing)

It uses CoreText to draw, and takes an NSAttributedString as a text store. You define your attributes (different font, size, etc) for a specific run of text, and this text view will draw that for you.

More specifically, you do this in your NSAttributedString, which you then set as the `attributedText`.

[Code is here](http://codaset.com/jer/jtextview).